# Change the datetime format from '2014-03-11T14:10:46+11:00' to '20140311141046+11:00'

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I am getting the dateTime value in the format `2014-03-11T14:10:46+11:00`.
I need to change this into the format `20140311141046+11:00`.

The method I am using right now is:

```
private string changeDateFormat()
{
     DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime("2014-03-11T14:10:46+11:00");           
     return dt.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
}
```

It seems to be working fine but with one catch.
Instead of showing the output like  `20140311141046+11:00`,
the output is `20140311084046`.

I think I need to pass the timezone too while converting to string. But I am blank on how to do that.

PS: This `+11:00` is dynamic can can change in the input. Please suggest a generic solution/approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you parse it to `DateTime` you lost the offset part.

I would parse it to [`DateTimeOffset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx) instead of `DateTime` and use [`K` format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#KSpecifier) with it's format like;

```
var str = "2014-03-11T14:10:46+11:00";
var dto = DateTimeOffset.Parse(str);
return dto.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssK");
```

returns

```
20140311141046+11:00
```

Comment: It doesn't hurt, and I notice your edit, but wouldn't you need the last parameter for a "non-invariant" culture only? Thus, simply: `return dto.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssK");`

Comment: @Gustav Yeah, since OP _already_ get `20140311084046` without any `IFormatProvider` in `ToString` method, it is not necessary on this case (it looks like op's current culture already uses gregorian calendar). But remember, it _might_ need some cases like if OP's `CurrentCulture` does not use Gregorian Calendar like `ar-SA` culture. This `dto.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssK", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ar-SA"))` generates `14350510141046+11:00` for example. But of course, it couldn't parse this string at first place with `DateTimeOffset.Parse(string)` method at all :)