# Read string value "yyyyMMddHHmmss" in DateTime type

Tags: c#, datetime

Here's my case.

I have a method `ISO8601DateTime_Local(DateTime dto)`

I cannot change its argument datatype as it will affect the entire solution.

Now I had a requirement to change the input date from `2014-03-11T14:10:46+11:00`
to `20140311141046+1100`

I have done it using the method below:

```
public string test1() {
        var str = "2014-03-11T14:10:46+11:00";
        var dto = DateTimeOffset.Parse(str);
        return dto.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssK");
}
```

Now I have to pass this test1 as argument in `ISO8601DateTime_Local()`
like

```
DateTime dt = ISO8601DateTime_Local(test1());
```

Please suggest.

Comment: A `DateTime` is not different based on a string format, so the only thing that matters is to change how you parse from any input string (if the input string format is changed).

Comment: You need to parse the datetime string back into a valid datetime to pass it into that function.

Comment: `dto.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK")`?

Comment: Isn't it the same question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33912018/change-the-datetime-format-from-2014-03-11t1410461100-to-201403111410461

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.datetime.parseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method with your format string:

```
DateTime dt = ISO8601DateTime_Local(DateTime.ParseExact(test1(), "yyyyMMddHHmmssK", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None));
```

(Maybe you want to use [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more stability)

I'm not sure about the `DateTimeStyles` argument, so check the [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/91hfhz89%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  if there is a more appropriate value than `DateTimeStyles.None` (especially `DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal` may be interesting).

Comment: I tried using DateTime.Parse but it returns 3/11/2014 8:40:46 AM eliminating the TimeZone value

Comment: I'm suprised that `Parse` instead of `ParseExact` works with this format at all. Must be your local `CultureInfo`. The correct call and result depends on what kind you want, local time or utc. Please try with `DateTimeStyles` like `AdjustToUniversal`, `AssumeUniversal` or `AssumeLocal`.